# Git Codeowners logic for multi team approvals

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise, github-codeowners

I am trying to figure out how to achieve the following behaviour using the CODEOWNERS file

- github group '@myorg/devops` can approve all pull requests in the repo
- github group '@myorg/devops' or group '@myorg/dev' can approve pull requests in dev1 and dev2 folders in the repo. This means one groups approval is sufficient.

Setup:

- Repository has branch protection rule for 'master `branch . This rule has 'Require review from Code Owners` flag switched on
- CODEOWNERS file saved in `.github/CODEOWNERS' and it has following content:

  ```
  *   @myorg/devops
  dev1/  @myorg/dev @myorg/devops
  dev2/  @myorg/dev @myorg/devops
  ```

Outcome:

When PR is done for files inside dev1 or dev2 folders, member of '@myorg/devops' approves it. Github however requests another approval from '@myorg/dev' group.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share a screenshot or error message?

According to the [document](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners) "or" statement works

> # In this example, any change inside the `/scripts` directory
>
> # will require approval from @doctocat or @octocat.
>
> /scripts/ @doctocat @octocat

By the way, it shouldn't matter if the owner is a user or a team.

> # Teams can be specified as code owners as well. Teams should
>
> # be identified in the format @org/team-name. Teams must have
>
> # explicit write access to the repository. In this example,
>
> # the octocats team in the octo-org organization owns all .txt files.
>
> *.txt @octo-org/octocats

My guess is that branch protection rule in your repository is saying that 2 approvals are needed for a PR.
See ["Require approvals" section in this page](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule)